# Stable mapping with ggplot2 scale_colour_discrete: drop does not work?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How to make `drop=TRUE` work (so legend contains only categories that exist in the subset) within `scale_colour_discrete` when using ggplot and trying to have stable colour mapping for categories in different plots?

This question is linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin) one and especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin#comment29248875_6924503) comment.

Reproducible code borrowed from [one of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21146026/4433666) in the linked question:

```
set.seed(2014)
library(ggplot2)
dataset <- data.frame(category = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 100),
                      x = rnorm(500, mean = rep(1:5, 100)),
                      y = rnorm(500, mean = rep(1:5, 100)))
dataset$fCategory <- factor(dataset$category)
subdata <- subset(dataset, category %in% c("A", "D", "E"))
ggplot(dataset, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fCategory)) + geom_point()
ggplot(subdata, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fCategory)) + geom_point() + 
       scale_colour_discrete(drop=TRUE,limits = levels(dataset$fCategory))
```

Why does the `drop=TRUE` not work in the second plot? The legend still contains all categories.

Output from `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United     Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.8     grid_3.1.2       gtable_0.1.2         labeling_0.3    
[6] MASS_7.3-35      munsell_0.4.2    plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10         Rcpp_0.11.3     
[11] reshape2_1.4.1   scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: I tried your example and I have stable mapping (i.e. categories A-E have the same colors in both plots) either with or without `drop=TRUE`. Could it be a version-related issue? I have ggplot2_1.0.0

Comment: @MaratTalipov Stable mapping works, but my question is concerned about drop=TRUE parameter not working. The legend in the second plot still contains all categories. I've edited my question to make it more clear and also added the session info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is either a misconception of what `drop` does (the help entry does not give much detail, unfortunately) or a bug. However, I'd recommend dropping `drop` altogether (pun intended) and setting both `limits` and `breaks`:

```
ggplot(subdata, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = fCategory)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_colour_discrete(limits = levels(dataset$fCategory), 
                        breaks = unique(subdata$fCategory))
```

[image]

The colour set is consistent, the legend is fine.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting breaks. I suggest you edit your answer to `breaks = unique(subdata$fCategory)` because we don't know which levels are present in advance.