# ggplot2: setting mapping for colour -> value, independently from values subset

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm working on making plots in R using ggplot2.

My plot looks like this:

```
values_range

ggplot(subset, aes(x, y, width = 0.5)) + 
geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(sort(values))), position = "stack", stat="identity")
```

where `values_range` is vector of all possible `values` and `subset` is subset of my data

How can I force ggplot to choose colors for `fill` always in the same way independently from `values` and `subset`

Eg. when `values_range =  [1, 2, 3, 4]` and for `subset1` `values = [1, 2, 3]` and for `subset2` `values = [1, 3, 4]`

I want `1, 2, 3, 4` values have the same colour in both `subset1` and `subset2` plots.
By default it is not in this way, ggplot would give the same colours for `2(1) - 3(2)` and `3(1) - 4(2)` values

Do you have any idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you attempting to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6919025/324364)?

Answer (score 0):

**convert your values to factor firstly**

```
data$values <- factor(data$values)
ggplot(subset, aes(x, y, width = 0.5)) + 
   geom_bar(aes(fill = values), position = "stack", stat="identity")
```