# Side-by-Side bar plots with consistent colour scheme

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been using a consistent [colour scheme](http://colorbrewer2.org/) across multiple bar plots using data from different data frames that share a common variable. This approach was based on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin). In each of these cases I was looking at one variable.

What I would like to do now is look at two variables on the same plot keeping the colour scheme consistent. It should look something like the following except the two bars for `A` should be the same colour (the first in the palette), the two bars for `B` should be the same colour (the second in the palette), etc. 
[image]

Sample data:

```
mydata <- data.frame( "Channel" = LETTERS[1:11], 
                  "V1" = seq(1100, 100, -100), 
                  "V2"= seq(110, 10, -10) )
```

and code for the above plot:

```
barplot(t(mydata[,2:3]), beside=T, 
    col=brewer.pal(11, "RdGy"), 
    names.arg=LETTERS[1:11])
```

I have been trying to do this in ggplot (which is my preference) but haven't succeeded. I have used the package `reshape2` to `melt` the data and then use `fill` but that only gets me two colours. I have also tried using `position='dodge'` in various ways with no luck. I can get to a similar end result combining a bar plot and a line graph for the second variable but would prefer the double bar plot.

I would also prefer to stick with ggplot but any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: The example code gives error `'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

Comment: @dww Sorry and thanks for catching. I was stuck in `ggplot2` mode and didn't convert argument to matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using a little hack. I set the color aesthetic to `Channel` and `family` to `variables`. The second one prevents that both `values` with the same `Channel` are plotted on top of each other when using `position = "dodge"`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

mydata <- data.frame( "Channel" = LETTERS[1:11], 
                      "V1" = seq(1100, 100, -100), 
                      "V2"= seq(110, 10, -10) )

df <- mydata %>% 
      melt(id = c("Channel"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Channel, y = value, fill = Channel, family = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "RdGy")
```

[image]

If you do not like the background you could use another theme. For example `theme_base()` from the `ggthemes` package should look similar to your `barplot`,

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just what I needed. And `ggplot` was the approach I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base graphics by specifying the colours to be repeated for each adjacent bar.

```
barplot(t(mydata[,2:3]), beside=T, col=rep(brewer.pal(11, "RdGy"), each=2), names.arg=LETTERS[1:11])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Always good to have more than one option and this code is a bit more straightforward.