# How can I fill and color based on a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

In my df I have a column which are color names ie red, green...
I want to use those colors for my filling and coloring. However I can't manage to plot it like that, and black is converted to orange, yellow is pink...

[image]

```
new.df <- structure(list(Expr = c(1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 
0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 
0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0, 1, 
0.75, 0.5, 0.25, 0), react = c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0.25, 
0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 
0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 
1, 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("black", "blue", "brown", "green", 
"pink", "red", "turquoise", "yellow"), class = c("ordered", "factor"
)), value = c(0.230403800475059, 0.0617577197149644, 0.0843230403800475, 
0.0819477434679335, 0.0819477434679335, 0.200712589073634, 0.187648456057007, 
0.144893111638955, 0.156769596199525, 0.142517814726841, 0.0451306413301663, 
0.114014251781473, 0.125890736342043, 0.133016627078385, 0.130641330166271, 
0.328978622327791, 0.0665083135391924, 0.0902612826603325, 0.0973871733966746, 
0.0855106888361045, 0.194774346793349, 0.0605700712589074, 0.0451306413301663, 
0.0700712589073634, 0.0653206650831354, NA, 0.0617577197149644, 
0.0605700712589074, 0.0795724465558195, 0.0783847980997625, NA, 
0.336104513064133, 0.0617577197149644, 0.0819477434679335, 0.0617577197149644, 
NA, 0.111638954869359, 0.0498812351543943, 0.168646080760095, 
0.0831353919239905)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .Names = c("Expr", 
"react", "variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
> scal <- scale_colour_manual(name = "variable", values = new.df$variable)
>   ggplot(new.df, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
+     facet_wrap(~Expr+react, labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line = FALSE)) +
+     geom_histogram(bins = 5) + theme_bw() + scal
```

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920045/2886003) answer I tried to create manually color scale, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change one line of your code:

```
scal <- scale_fill_manual(values = unique(as.character(new.df$variable)))
```

and keep the remaining part as it is:

```
ggplot(new.df, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
  facet_wrap(~Expr+react, labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line = FALSE)) +
  geom_histogram(bins = 5) + theme_bw() + scal
```

to get this output:

[image]

Comment: it is the same solution as mine. I only also transformed the original variable in an ordered factor, so to be safer (I know that most of the time is useless, but I always do that when I want to control how aestetics are assigned).

Comment: ok don't worry, it was just to remark it. The essential thing we only should care about is to provide an adequate answer for the community ;) I am just "disappointed" I wasted my precious time helping the OP in both the comment section and the SO chat, then the OP decided to accept an equivalent answer, which is totally fair according to SO's regulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
new.df$variable <- ordered(new.df$variable, levels = unique(new.df$variable))

ggplot(new.df, aes(x = value, fill = variable)) +
facet_wrap(~Expr+react, labeller = label_wrap_gen(multi_line = FALSE)) +
geom_histogram(bins = 5) + theme_bw() +
scale_fill_manual(name = "variable", 
                    values = unique(as.character(new.df$variable)))
```

Then re-execute the ggplot command.

Ps: there is a typo in your code, I think: you wrote

```
values = new.df$variables
```

instead of `values = new.df$variable`

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work (even with the typo corrected). Why should the order of it affect the colors ggplot2 is using?

Comment: `scale_colour_manual(name = "variable", values = unique(new.df$variable))`

Comment: can you `dput()` your data or a sample of it? It is difficult to think of an answer without being able to try it on data

Comment: I already post the head of my new.df, but I can post the whole data if you wish

Comment: better.. or at least a random sample that contains all colors. Use `dput(new.df)`, then copy-paste here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126608/discussion-between-llopis-and-davide-passaretti).

Comment: black is black, but green is brown... and so on.