# Properly ordered factor in ggplot is not working with fill_color_manual

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting a filled contour plot using a combination of stat_contour and geom_tile. There is a strange thing happening where, despite having checked the factor levels and the color vector, the colors sometimes do not correspond to the correct level.

Example 1: The colors are matching properly

Breaks:

```
 [1] "[1.2e-06,1.25e-06]" "(1.25e-06,1.3e-06]"
 [3] "(1.3e-06,1.35e-06]" "(1.35e-06,1.4e-06]"
 [5] "(1.4e-06,1.45e-06]" "(1.45e-06,1.5e-06]"
 [7] "(1.5e-06,1.55e-06]" "(1.55e-06,1.6e-06]"
 [9] "(1.6e-06,1.65e-06]" "(1.65e-06,1.7e-06]"
```

Colors:

```
 [1] "#FFFF00" "#8DFF00" "#1CFF00" "#00AA54"
 [5] "#0038C6" "#2307FB" "#6A15F5" "#AA1CD5"
 [9] "#D40E6A" "#FF0000"
```

Result:

[image: Example 1]

Example 2: The colors are not matching properly (the first bin is the last color!)

Breaks:

```
 [1] "[100,110]" "(110,120]" "(120,130]"
 [4] "(130,140]" "(140,150]" "(150,160]"
 [7] "(160,170]" "(170,180]" "(180,190]"
[10] "(190,200]" "(200,210]"
```

Colors:

```
 [1] "#FFFF00" "#99FF00" "#32FF00" "#00CB33"
 [5] "#006599" "#0000FF" "#400CF9" "#8019F3"
 [9] "#B319BF" "#D90C5F" "#FF0000"
```

Result:

[image: Example 2]

As you can see, in both instances the first binned range should correspond to yellow, but in the second case the color being filled in is red!

I've attached the function [at this pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/S9v8pxhq) but here's the relevant snippet:

```
            geom_tile(data=longdata_n,aes(x=lons[longdata_n[,1]],
                     y=lats[longdata_n[,2]],fill=brks),alpha=0.5) +
            geom_tile(data=longdata_s,aes(x=lons[longdata_s[,1]],
                     y=lats[longdata_s[,2]],fill=brks),alpha=0.5) +
    scale_fill_manual(breaks=lev_order,values=contour_cols) +
```

EDIT to add additional information:

I suspect it has something to do with how the order of the factors is being interpreted within `scale_color_manual`, because when I change the line to

`scale_fill_manual(values=contour_cols)` without specifying the breaks, this is what it looks like:

[image: New example]

Note that while the color scheme has stayed the same, the first factor level is now located at the bottom. Is there a hack to fix this?

Comment: You could either set the order of your factor levels in the dataset prior to plotting or you can set the names of your color vector with your vector of breaks.  See, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920045/2461552) for an example of the latter.

Comment: Oh wow! Adding the names to the color vector did it!!!!

Comment: Naming color vectors is often the safest route, but the real issue stems from how you split your original dataset in two for plotting. Since each subset has distinct "breaks" values, ggplot2 has to turn the variable into characters to combine the values and then factors again.  Look at the factor level order for variables like yours if they are character variables: `levels(factor(c("[100,110]","(110,120]", "(200,210]")))` and `levels(factor(c("(90,100]","(100,110]", "(200,210]")))`.

Comment: To avoid dropping unused factor levels in each subset and the subsequent refactoring, use `drop = FALSE` in `scale_fill_manual` instead of the default `drop = TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to aosmith for the tip!

Adding names to the color contour caused them to properly correspond, even though the order was still messed up for some reason if I didn't specify the `breaks=` parameter within `scale_fill_manual`. I did this to fix the ordering problem:

```
lev_order<-levels(as.factor(longdata$breaks))
contour_cols<-colorRampPalette(c("yellow","green","blue","purple","red"))(length(lev_order))
names(contour_cols) <- lev_order
```

Everything else works! It now looks as it should:

[image]