# create a google map of USA with long and lat columns and earnings

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a map of USA with points of earnings by state.

for example I have these data:

```
    state   capital_name     lat        long      women    earning            
1   Alabama   Montgomery   32.36154  -86.27912     621       832    
2    Alaska     Juneau     58.30194  -134.41974    797      1008 
3    Arizona   Phoenix     33.44846  -112.07384    669       827  
4    Arkansas Little Rock  34.73601  -92.33112     610       703
```

For now this is my code:

```
 mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + 
              geom_point(aes(x = lat, y = long, size = sqrt(women_median_weekly_earnings)),   
                         data = join2, alpha = .5 ,color="darkred") +
              scale_size(range=c(3,20))

 map <- get_map(location = 'usa', zoom = 4)

 mapPoints
```

This what I get:
[image]

As you can see, the points are not on the map.
What is wrong with the code?

How can I fix it?

Thank you very much

Comment: You don't have a column `women_median_weekly_earnings`

Comment: Try different zoom levels to first see if it is being plotted at all. Because the legend is there.. it seems there must be some data...

Comment: yes, I tried to zoom in, its not even being plotted. and I dont know where and how to insert a colomn of women_median_weekly_earnings.

Comment: what do I need to write in the code for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake in aesthetics; **y  is latitude (north-south), x longitude (west-east)**, not the opposite.

Here, your code is looking, for example, for `Alabama`, for `32.36154` on the `x axis`, and `-86.27912` on the `y axis`. There's not within the limits of the map supplied, so this point won't be visible.

You should get things done by reversing `lat` and `long` in your `aes`.

Also, `zoom = 3` seems to be the right zoom to get all the points within the map

---

```
library(ggmap)

map <- map<-get_map(location='united states', zoom=3, maptype = "terrain",
                source='google',color='color')
mapPoints <- ggmap(map) + 
                         geom_point(aes(y = lat, x = long, size = sqrt(earning)), 
             data = df, alpha = .5 ,color="darkred") +
                                                      scale_size(range=c(3,20))

mapPoints
```

[image]

***Data:***

```
df <- read.table(text='state    capital_name    lat long    women   earning
                       Alabama  Montgomery  32.36154    -86.27912   621 832
                       Alaska   Juneau  58.30194    -134.41974  797 1008
                       Arizona  Phoenix 33.44846    -112.07384  669 827
                       Arkansas LittleRock  34.73601    -92.33112   610 703',  
                       header = T, quote = '"')
```

Comment: No problem, please do !

Comment: Try to make your answers well-formatted, clean, precise, complete but not unnecessarily long. You can read my comment on the edits if you wish. This way you'd get more reputation as your answer appears to be more professional on the first glance. Cheers.

Comment: thanks Colin. I did what you say about the long and lat. It's hepped. but now I have large circles on the map and that a great progress. How do I differentiate between men and women?

Comment: @GiladUzan to assign color to a group var, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin. Also, as it solves your question, can you please accept the answer I've given? Tbanks, Colin.