# R ggplot2 how to set colors for Categorical Variable for multiple plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, categorical-data, timeserieschart

I had a question regarding how one can set the colors for a categorical variable before any plot is produced. To be clear, I am aware of scale_manual_fill. However, the issue is I am looking at time series data and not all the categorical variables will show up each year. Therefore, I am trying to find a way to set the values in the categorical variable equal to specific colors in a way such that they will remain those colors for any plot after when one sets fill = that categorical variable. This would allow me to run my plots and not have to worry about which value of the categorical variable is present during the specific year.

Comment: So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin) is not what you're after? Can you make a small example which demonstrates your problem?

Comment: That should work! I never saw that. I saw other questions/answer suggesting to use Scale_manual_fill on each of the plots to set specific colors.