# legend does not follow ordered bars in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

My plot has two problems:

(1) the group bars are not ordered as I want them to be - I will like them to appear in the order entered and (2) for the legend, the order appears as **V, E, B** whereas in the groups, it appears as **B, E, V**. I can reverse the legend, however, what I will really like to get is change the order of the subplots to **V, E, B**.

```
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- data.frame(supp = rep(c("V","E","B"), each=5),
                  s = rep(c("C3","C1", "C2","C5","C6"), 3),
                  len = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,4,4,3,9,7,6,8,5))

p <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = s, y = len, fill = supp)) + 
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge())

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
      scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df2$s)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data**

```
df2 <- data.frame(supp = rep(c("V", "E", "B"), each = 5),
                  s = rep(c("C3", "C1", "C2", "C5", "C6"), 3),
                  len = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 4, 4, 3, 9, 7, 6, 8, 5))
```

**Adjustment**

Because you use `data.frame()` to create data, R will set strings as factors by default. So you need to revise the types of variables to what you want.

```
df2$s <- as.character(df2$s)
df2$supp <- factor(df2$supp, levels = c("V", "E", "B"))
```

**Plot**

```
ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = s, y = len, fill = supp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues", direction = -1)
```

Here you don't need to use additional `guide_legend()` and `scale_x_discrete()` to change order. It will be more concise.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `df2$supp` from character to factor and specify the levels as you want them to appear.

See modified code below. Also, check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin#comment29248875_6924503) for even more detail about how to control the colour of your variables so they are consistent.

```
library(ggplot2)

df2 <- data.frame(supp = rep(c("V","E","B"), each=5),
                  s = rep(c("C3","C1", "C2","C5","C6"), 3),
                  len = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,4,4,3,9,7,6,8,5))

df2$supp <- factor(df2$supp,
                   levels = c("V", "E", "B"))

p <- ggplot(data=df2, aes(x=(df2$s), y=len, fill=supp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", position=position_dodge())

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues", guide = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(df2$s)))
```

[image]

Comment: I edit your answer by adding a plot of output to make it more clear. You can check whether it's created by your code. Hope that I don't offend you.

Comment: That’s a good point. That would have been helpful in my answer and I will use it for the future! No offence taken here!