# Add color to specific categorical variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I would like to add color to a specific categorical variable. For instance, I want to highlight (by adding color) setosa species specifically; for the rest of species (such as virginica and versicolor), just black dots. I guess there should be an easy way to do this. I am pretty new to R.

```
data(iris)
library(ggplot2)
#This is not desirable
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + geom_point(aes(colour=Species))
#This is what I aim to achieve, but it is not working
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width)) + geom_point() + geom_point(aes(colour=Species$setosa))
```

[image]

Comment: Have you come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin)?

Comment: I'd suggest some reading of this source here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments and references!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give colors manually to each level using `scale_color_manual`

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_color_manual(values = c('setosa' = 'Blue', 'versicolor' = 'black', 
                                  'virginica' = 'black'))
```

[image]

---

If there are many such levels and it is not possible to assign colors to all those manually, we can create a named vector as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6920045/3962914) answer.

```
color_vec <- rep("black", length(unique(iris$Species)))
names(color_vec) <- unique(iris$Species)
color_vec[names(color_vec) == "setosa"] <- "blue"
```

and use this in `scale_color_manual`

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Width, color = Species)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_color_manual(values = color_vec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could try making a new variable with a binary field for Setosa vs. Other and use that as the color aesthetic:

```
library(tidyverse)
data(iris)

iris %>% 
  mutate(Species2 = if_else(Species == "setosa", "Setosa", "Versicolor/Virginica")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width, color = Species2)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This is also very illuminating!