# How to assign colors to categorical variables with a stable mapping in R highcharter?

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How can I assign colors to a categorical variable in R highcharter with a stable mapping? I want to use consistent colors across a huge set of figures that have different subsets of this variable. Therefore, I want to define the color mapping globally for all figures.

There is a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919025/how-to-assign-colors-to-categorical-variables-in-ggplot2-that-have-stable-mappin) using `ggplot2`. I tried to use the solutions in my case, but so far without success.

This is a minimal example of my data:

| faculty | cost |
| --- | --- |
| physics | 8000 |
| life sciences | 1050 |
| chemistry | 1000 |

Here is my code so far:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

ColorPalette <- c("green","blue","red")
names(ColorPalette) <- levels(publications$faculty)

hchart(
  publications,
  "column",
  hcaes(x = faculty, y = cost),
  colorByPoint = TRUE
  ) %>%
  hc_colors(ColorPalette)
```

Using the defined colors works fine, but when I create figures with a subset of the data only containing some values of the categorical variable, color assignment gets mixed up and is not stable:

- [first plot with defined colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7qIH.jpg)
- [second plot with a subset and mixed up colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbNyr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is assigning the colors (In CSS style using this site: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.html) to the different faculty values using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(highcharter)

publications <- data.frame(faculty = c("physics", "life sciences", "chemistry"),
                           cost = c(8000, 1050, 1000))

publications <- mutate(publications, color = ifelse(faculty == "physics", "#00FF00", 
                                             ifelse(faculty == "life sciences", "#0000FF", "#FF0000")))
```

You don't need to use `hc_colors`, because you can assign the colors in the `hcaes` using this code:

```
hchart(
  publications,
  "column",
  hcaes(x = faculty, y = cost, color = color),
  colorByPoint = TRUE
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: To add the color assignment in a separate column in the dataframe solves my question. Is there a way to map colours for various dataframes all containing faculty as a variable, or do I have to assign the colours in each dataframe via `mutate`?

Comment: @taze4, Great to hear that solved your question. If the colors are faculty dependent you need to assign them via `mutate`.