# R: keep factor levels for legend order in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a code that I use on multiple datasets.  Datasets always contain two groups, one of which is always "Control", while the second group varies between datasets.

When I plot the data I want Control to appear first in the Legend and be assigned the color black, and the other group to appear second and orange.  Despite multiple attempts to factor the groups, Control will only appear first when it is alphabetically first.  When factoring and defining levels, I can't explicitly call the second group because it varies between datasets, but the method I use does appear to factor the dataset properly.  However, the Legend order still sorts alphabetically.

I provided a simplified example below.  How can I get the Control group to always appear first in the Legend?  Am I factoring incorrectly?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

samples <- data.frame(
  ID=paste0(rep(c("P"),12), c(1:12)),
  Treatment=c(rep(LETTERS[1:2], 6))
  )
  
samples <- samples %>%
  dplyr::filter(ID =="P1" | ID =="P6") %>%
  dplyr::mutate(Condition= ifelse(Treatment == "B", "Control", "Anesthesia"))

#Factor Conditions so that Control comes before Anesthesia
samples$Condition <- ordered(samples$Condition, levels=c("Control", paste0(samples$Condition[samples$Treatment == "A"])))


df <- data.frame(
  Position=c(rep(1:500, 2)),
  ID=c(rep("P1", 500), rep("P6", 500)),
  Condition=c(rep("Anesthesia", 500), rep("Control", 500)),
  Signal=c(rep(5, 500), rep(25,500))
  )

#Set desired colors for plot
colorscale <- c(adjustcolor("black", 0.5), adjustcolor("orange", 0.8))

#Make plot
Plot <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_line(aes(x=Position, y=Signal, col=Condition)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = colorscale)
```

```
#Confirm that factoring works...
samples$Condition

> samples$Condition
[1] Anesthesia Control   
Levels: Control < Anesthesia
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: You have set the order of levels verified that the factors levels are in the correct order in the `samples` data frame. But you don't plot the samples data frame, you plot using `data = df`, where the `Condition` column is in the default (alphabetical) order.

Comment: The best general solution is to use a named vector in `scale_color_manual`. You can define `my_cols = c("Control" = adjustcolor("black", 0.5), "Anesthesia" = adjustcolor("orange", 0.8))` and then use `scale_color_manual(breaks = my_cols)`. See the 2nd example at the `?scale_color_manual` help page, under *`# It's recommended to use a named vector`*.

Comment: Though, if your case is more complicated, note that (again from the `?scale_color_manual` help page) `breaks` can be *"A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output"* - so you could right a function that puts `Control` first and then returns any other levels in alphabetical order, as a named vector, with whatever colors you want. Something like `my_col_function = function(x) {setNames(c(adjustcolor("black", 0.5), adjustcolor("orange", 0.8)), c("Control", setdiff(x, "Control"))}`

Comment: I spent an embarrassingly long time reviewing and modifying my factoring method on `samples$Condition`, wondering why it wasn't working.  Sigh.  Would you like to post a solution factoring the `df$Condition` in the way I've factored `samples$Condition`, or would you prefer I append my question to contain the solution?

Comment: Frankly I think deleting the question or closing it as a typo is the best course. Or maybe closing as a duplicate of, e.g., [How to assign colors to categorical variables in ggplot2 that have a stable mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6919025/903061). (I've already voted to close as Typo, so I can't close as a duplicate.)

Comment: @GregorThomas Done, closed as duplicate.